# smbclient/mount.cifs both failing to connect

Tags: linux, networking, samba

Can anyone help me here?
I've tried reinstalling and other various things that I've found listed online.

I have 2 Arch linux boxes. One is my home computer and one is my web server.

Using the same exact configuration my home computer can be mounted fine from another computer but my server's share is failing - even though the "twmasterbackup" share worked perfectly fine 2 weeks ago.

You'll see a few commented out lines in the configuration. I tried with these enabled/disabled and various combinations of.

Actual IP addresses will be changed to XX.XX.XX.XX format.

I haven't changed anything on the server since I last accessed the backup except adding more IP addresses. Today neither the backup nor the http share are working.

Mounting is giving "mount error(115): Operation now in progress".
smbclient is simply timing out.

Command to connect:

```
smbclient -U http '//XX.XX.XX.XX/twhttp' ************
```

Configuration on XX.XX.XX.XX:

```
    #======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]
workgroup = TWMASTER
server string = TWMASTER
#   socket address = XX.XX.XX.XX
#   interfaces = eth0
#   bind interfaces only = yes
#   hosts allow = 192.168.1. 192.168.2. 127. YY.YY.YY.YY
load printers = no
log file = /var/log/samba/twmaster.log
max log size = 50
security = user
dns proxy = no
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[twmasterbackup]
comment = MasterBackup
path = /home/backup/backup
public = no
valid users = backup
writable = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
printable = no
[twhttp]
comment = http
path = /home/http
public = no
valid users = http
writable = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
printable = no
```

Comment: Thank you Marius. It's quite a busy day so I haven't had the time myself hence posting the question here in the first place. I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with this samba problem. Some theories on other forums are that maybe my ISP started blocking the ports. I'm going to check into that but for someone looking for a quick workaround, google sshfs ... I use ssh and scp every day but failed to think of this. It saved me yesterday.